# Magento Language File for Admin-Customer Account Page

Tags: magento, localization, magento-1.4

Maybe I'm just tired...but I can't seem to locate the language file relevant to the backend Customers>Manage Customers>Individual Record

I just want to change the form label "Suffix" to "Credentials".

Answer (score 1):

Can you use [inline translation](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/inline-translation-in-magento/) to do it?